# Spring batch integration with quartz

Tags: quartz-scheduler, spring-batch

How to run three spring batch jobs sequentially..
i created three batch jobs and one cron trigger expression. i need to run three jobs sequentially when first batch job completed successfully then second batch job and then third batch job...

for example:1st batch job will give input to second, second atch job will give input to 3rd and then 3rd will process it...

Answer (score 0):

For sequential execution see [§5.3.1 Sequential Flow](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#SequentialFlow):

```
<job id="job">
    <step id="stepA" parent="s1" next="stepB" />
    <step id="stepB" parent="s2" next="stepC"/>
    <step id="stepC" parent="s3" />
</job>
```

The output of each step should be file, or DB records. In this case Spring batch has an ability to restart the job execution from interrupted (failed) step (see also [§5.1.4.2 Restarting a completed step](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#allowStartIfComplete)). Inter-step communication is possible via `ExecutionContext` (see [`StepExecution`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/StepExecution.html) and [`StepExecutionListener`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/StepExecutionListener.html))

If you don't want to dump intermediate results, you don't need need sequential step execution: you simply feed the output of one processor to another.